# Is my computer being hacked? How can wireshark reveal if I am being hacked?

Tags: vpn, wireshark

So last night I was using openVPN via my personal cloud server to watch some Hulu.

About 15 minutes into the movie I noticed my network stats were

download: ~250 MB
upload: ~1.8 GB

This is according the the openVPN software.

I paused my movie and the download stopped but my upload jumped from 1.8 to 1.9 and stopped at 2.1 in less than 5 minutes.

I only start my VPN to watch movies and my stats reset everytime I disconnect.

I wasn't torrenting and no other software was running that uses network traffic (to my knowledge).

This strikes me as highly suspicious. I ran anti-virus and anti-spyware scans on my system and found nothing.

**How can I use wireshark to tell if I'm being hacked?**

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk, but have you gone through [Wireshark documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/)? There's some nice videos even, [user guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/), you name it. Your question is really not specific enough and this Q&A format here isn't all that suitable for writing complete how-to guides. Please refer to [FAQ], [Ask] and [About] pages here for more information. Thanks!

Comment: You could simply have fired up wireshark. The protocol, source and destination columns can give a good indication, what's going on. Then, if you don't know how to interpret results, ask again.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, in your situation, you likely have already been hacked, and malicious software is sending traffic. Wireshark can help to confirm this and to characterize the type of infection.

Turn off as many services as you can, close all browsers, then confirm that the upload is occurring. Turn on Wireshark to monitor the traffic.

Wireshark might be able to identify it right away, but it does still require some interpretation of the data it displays. Perhaps most importantly, find out the destination of all the major traffic and use a whois lookup to see who it is that you are communicating with.

In the end, you will have to be prepared to scrub your machine, or blow it away and start from scratch.

Comment: Unless it's a browser plug-in leak.